# how can you add ñ and tildes in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

It turns out that I want to put ñ and accents, but flutter recognizes them with symbols of "?" in a rhombus, I tried several methods but I couldn't get it.

[image: Flutter character]

Answer (score 1):

the solution I found was to use the unicode, the "ñ" comes out as the following U+00F1, but in flutter it is placed like this \u{00F1}, leaving for example "Ingrese contrase\u{00F1}a".

```
the other unicodes for accents or tildes are:
á: \u{00E1}
é: \u{00E9}
í: \u{00ED}
ó: \u{00F3}
ú: \u{00FA}
```